# how do i enable text input in a select element? (js or jQuery)

Tags: jquery-selectors

how do i enable text input in a select element in order to both manually input a any numeric value or choose from a select having limited options?
For example desktop applications such as photoshop, adjusting character size!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the JQuery plugin [Editable Select](http://www.jqueryplugins.com/plugin/254/)

Comment: Thnx cjimti i think i have found it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to go with a normal text `input` and mimic the select element using a dropdown `div`, similarly to what Google does to provide search suggestions.

Comment: Thanx RegDwight i had thought of that but how to i include a down row which one can click for a drop down to appear? more help on this pliz